# Hangman game : list.remove is removing the wrong item, but only when all items are the same. If I change them to different ones, it works

Tags: python, list

So this game is hangman and the list wordFinder holds as many underscores as the letters in the word you are trying to guess. When you guess correctly, it should remove the underscore respective to the letter you guessed, so that it can then insert it back into it's place. This works fine usually, apart from when you guess a letter that comes after another letter in the word that you have already guessed. This causes the program to remove the wrong underscore, and it shifts the letters to the left.

ex) for bear:  _ e _ _  => guess=a  => removes the first underscore, => e _ a _

here is the section of code for this adding and removing:

```
for i in range(len(word)):
                    if guess==word[i]:
                        print(i)
                        found=found+1
                        print("Going to remove",i," which is ",wordFinder[i])
                        wordFinder.remove(wordFinder[i])
                        print(wordFinder)
                        if i==(len(word)-1):
                            print("last letter so add on end")
                            wordFinder.append(guess)
                        else:
                            print("Inserting at ",i)
                            wordFinder.insert(i,guess)
                             
                    else:
                        print("Wrong guess!")
                        pass
```

where word is the word you are guessing, found is just a counter for how many letters you have got
wordFinder is ["*","*","*","*"] in the case of bear
note: when i change these underscores to different characters eg (, . -) the problem doesnt happen

I tried everything - but the note above is interesting.
I don't know why this is happening but any help would be really appreciated

Comment: you can iterate word by doing `for character in word:`, which will give you directly the character. If you also need the index you can do `for i, character in enumerate(word):`

Comment: Please explain how your question is related to `sql-insert` which is one of tags you have used.

Comment: @Daweo : removing the tag from the question would save you time for writing the request for explanation where it apparently can't by any which would make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of the problem you have experienced is the method you use to remove an item from a list:

```
wordFinder.remove(wordFinder[i])
```

In case there are multiple occurrences of the same character in `wordFinder` the first found (*`.remove(value)` searches in the list for `value` and if it finds one removes it from the list*) one will be removed. In case `i` addresses not the first occurrence of `value` then the wrong character will be removed from the list. If you use only different characters than the right one will be found as there is no ambiguity involved if more than one occurrence of same value is present in the list.

This above answers the question: *I don't know why is this happening?*

You can fix the problem with ambiguity removing the character at index `i` using `.pop(i)`:

```
wordFinder.pop(i)
```

instead.